# Data structure in List

Tags: c++, list

```
template <class type> class list
{

private:
    struct element
    {
        type data;
        element* prev;
        element* next;

    };
    element* begin;
    element* end;
    int size;

public:
    list()
    {
        begin = NULL;
        end = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    // data is copied twice. (why? how to solve it?)
    void add_at_beginning(type data) 
    {
        element* temp = new element;
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev = NULL;
        temp->data = data;
        if (size == 0)
        {
            begin = end = temp;
            size++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = begin;
            begin->prev = temp;
            begin = temp;
            size++;
        }
    }
};
```

In the function called `void add_at_beginning(type data)` there is a problem, I wrote the problem in a comment.

Namely I don't understand what it means to say that data is copied twice, and most importantly how can I solve this problem so that nobody says that in this code data is copied twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `void add_at_beginning(type data)` takes its data argument by value, this means that when you call the function, a copy of data is made.

Then when you assign `temp->data = data;`, a second copy is made.
That's why you've been told that in your code data is copied twice.

You can avoid one of those copies by taking your data argument by reference. This may result in some performance improvements if your class is used with large types.

If you change your function's prototype to :

```
void add_at_beginning(const type& data)
```

Then only one copy will be made.

Comment: Thank you for your useful response. So data is copied already only in temp->data = data ? And what this approach actually gives us ? I mean it it optimizes our code  or our code will run faster? I'd like to understand these things more deeper.

Comment: Yes, now there's only one copy made, when you do `temp->data = data`. It should make your code a bit faster in the general case, but it really depends on how you use your class. If you want to use your class with large, unmoveable objects then it's a great optimization to do. But if you're just storing ints, then it might not help you much.